# eBay API AddItem call on India site returns 'Sales Tax / VAT was dropped from the listing' error

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am totally new to any sort of API application. Right now I am creating a listing application to list items on E-bay India site. 
API version being used is 767, 
sandbox url is https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi.
I have sandbox account for ebay(buyer/seller) and developer account.

I am getting error saying:
1) Sales Tax / VAT was dropped from the listing as per new sales tax / VAT policy. The items will be listed successfully, you may revise the listing to specify all inclusive price.
2) You have either not registered or are having problem with your payment method registration.

```
ItemType type = new ItemType();
 type.PaymentMethods = new BuyerPaymentMethodCodeTypeCollection();
 type.PaymentMethods.Add(BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType.PaisaPayAccepted);
```

Also do I have to specify taxation for each state?
For VAT and shipping details here's my snippet:

```
private ShippingDetailsType getShippingDetails()
        {
            // Shipping details.
            ShippingDetailsType sd = new ShippingDetailsType();          
            SalesTaxType salesTax = new SalesTaxType();
            ReadSettings rs = new ReadSettings();
            rs.GetSettings();
            salesTax.SalesTaxPercent = 12f;
            salesTax.SalesTaxState = "MH";
            SalesTaxType s = new SalesTaxType();
            salesTax.ShippingIncludedInTax = true;
            salesTax.ShippingIncludedInTaxSpecified = true;
            sd.ApplyShippingDiscount = true;
            AmountType at = new AmountType();
            at.Value = 2.8;
            at.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.INR;
            sd.InsuranceFee = at;
            sd.InsuranceOption = InsuranceOptionCodeType.NotOffered;
            sd.PaymentInstructions = "These are my instructions.";
            VATDetailsType vd = new VATDetailsType();
            vd.BusinessSeller = false;
            vd.BusinessSellerSpecified = false;
            vd.RestrictedToBusiness = false;
            vd.RestrictedToBusinessSpecified = false;
            vd.VATID = "VATSNO1234567890";
            vd.VATPercent = 12f;
            vd.VATPercentSpecified = true;
            vd.VATSite = "None";

            sd.ShippingType = ShippingTypeCodeType.Flat;
            //
            ShippingServiceOptionsType st1 = new ShippingServiceOptionsType();
            sd.SalesTax = salesTax;
            st1.ShippingService = ShippingServiceCodeType.IN_Express.ToString();
            at = new AmountType();
            at.Value = 50;
            at.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.INR;
            st1.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = at;
            at = new AmountType();
            at.Value = 50;
            at.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.INR;
            st1.ShippingServiceCost = at;
            st1.ShippingServicePriority = 1;
            at = new AmountType();
            at.Value = 1.0;
            at.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.INR;
            st1.ShippingInsuranceCost = at;
            sd.ShippingServiceOptions = new ShippingServiceOptionsTypeCollection(new ShippingServiceOptionsType[] { st1 });
            return sd;
        }
```

*Thank you for you efforts.*

Answer (score 0):

So, from Ebay's `.IN` site. http://pages.ebay.in/help/sell/new-sales-tax-policy.html
You will need to revise your listing(s) to include the total (all inclusive) price.

Code wise:

```
// Before you assign the Item's price
allInclusiveItemPrice = itemPrice * VAT; // Sales tax also if needed

Then set the item.price = allInclusiveItemPrice //BuyItNowPrice or Auction price
```

I'm not sure how setting taxation rates for India would work in general.
Also
2) You have either not registered or are having problem with your payment method registration.
Could be a problem. I'm not sure what the error means in this context.